# Can I change my OS X theme?

Tags: macos, settings, desktop, 3rd-party, themes

Some of my friends said that OS X sucks because you only have to choose one theme on every device that have OS X. I searched, but I didn't find any feasible solution just one little thing that cost money (and I didn't want to risk it).

Is there a easy way to change OS X themes that is free? Please don't tell me that the theme doesn't need to be changed; I really want something like Ubuntu that can change anything, I really love my Ubuntu desktop (KDE and Gnome).

If OS X doesn't do this, are there any 3rd-party utilities that can?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Out of the box there is no themeing capability in Mac OS X, you can however modify some of the colours used by Mac OS X in the Appearance Preference Pane in System Preferences.

If you're serious about themeing however there are 3rd party applications you can get to help with this:

- [CandyBar](http://panic.com/candybar/) - manages and changes icons.
- [ThemePark](http://www.geekspiff.com/software/themepark/) - does most everything else. If you're interested in available themes that work with ThemePark check out [MacThemes](http://macthemes.net/wiki/10.6_Available_Themes)

Otherwise a fairly good resource is the forum at [MacThemes](http://macthemes.net/forum/).

Comment: Your links give 404 except candybar

Answer (score 4):

There is now an app called [Flavours](http://flavours.interacto.net/) that allows theming. It has many nice themes, including some Shapeshifter themes, and runs starting on Lion (10.7.x) up to Mavericks (10.9.x). It costs a bit, however.

Answer (score 2):

These days, there's also [PaintCan](https://github.com/MacEnhance/PaintCan) which is a plugin for [MacForge](https://www.macenhance.com/macforge.html).

Answer (score 1):

Back in the 10.4 days there was [Shapeshifter](http://www.unsanity.com/haxies/shapeshifter) from [Unsanity](http://www.unsanity.com/). Sadly, it died when Leopard was released.