# The state of theming in OS X

Tags: macos, dock, icon, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change my OS X theme?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256/can-i-change-my-os-x-theme)

There used to be a vibrant community of themers and modders for OS X. It seems like after Leopard was released a lot of that has dried up. This may be the one area where I envy Windows users. The flexibility they have in changing every aspect of the UI is really nice.

Are there any resources for people looking to change the look of our OS?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256/can-i-change-my-os-x-theme