# What is the leading alternative OS X theme solution?

Tags: macos, themes

Is there a leading alternate theme solution for OS X? I'm not looking for anything tacky - I'd rather just endure the grey if there aren't any good solutions out there.

However, if there is anything really nice, I'd love to know about it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change my OS X theme?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256/can-i-change-my-os-x-theme)