# OSX EL Captain customization and themeing

Tags: macos, customization, themes

*I don't like the new dock, I don't like the new folders, I don't like flat* or may be I am bored of looking at same stuff. But really I still miss OSX Lion/Mavericks 3D dock and a more lively user interface.

I am a big fan of Ubuntu, Arch Linux. I go to [noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/) every once a week to customize my pc. I easily get bored of looking at same think for a long time.

What am I already using for customization:

1) [LiteIcon](https://freemacsoft.net/liteicon/) for changing app and custom icons which I usually grab from [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/) **{disable SIP}**

2) [cDock](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdock/) for custom Docks **{disable SIP}**

3) [Xtra Finder](https://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) & [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) for more enhanced and shortcuts **{disable SIP}**

4) [iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com/) and [Oh-My-Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) for a better shell

5) [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) in place of spotlight with custom themes

6) [Irvue](http://irvue.tumblr.com/) for OSX to grab Hi-Res wallpaper from unsplash automatically

Are there any suggestions for creating better User Interface , customization, Personalize better? Any cool app for widgets, any kind of amazing stuff.

NOTE: This is not just a question. This post is more of like a Wiki. Everyone can post there cool, customization apps, tweaks, scripts, anything here. This is an effort to grow the apple stack exchange community and make it more fun. Thanks.

Request: Please don't downvote, keep on hold as personal opinion etc. You can however edit this question. I am still asking for better customization apps.

[What is SIP?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really)

[How to disable SIP?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11)

[I have disabled SIP but why shouldn't you disable it?](http://www.imore.com/el-capitan-system-integrity-protection-helps-keep-malware-away) Know what you are doing. I am not encouraging anyone to compromise his/her security

Comment: This will probably be more on topic on [softwarerecs.se]. And StackOverflow doesn't allow "wikis" and questions asking for "good books for so-and-so programming language". Those are off topic. The ones that do exist are old and only remain because they have "historical significance"

Comment: The most recent re-evaluation of list-type questions I can find is this - [Re-evaluating “list of tips” type questions](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/re-evaluating-list-of-tips-type-questions) which would seem to say they're OK. However, for it to be a *good* list question, the list ought to be in the answers, not in the question. Having said that, 'customising OS X' questions already exist - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256/can-i-change-my-os-x-theme

Comment: @Tetsujin so I have modified the question and I am mostly targeting SIP now. So, its exclusively for EL Captain now.

Answer (score 3):

Amazing post I wished to write a blog post about this same topic. For yosemite you had Flavour 2 for customizing. The was large of people contributing there themes. But, the support for Flavour 2 had ended. They won't support EL Captain because of SIP

[**El Capitan Means The End Of Mac Themes & Deep System Tweaks**](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/el-capitan-end-mac-customization/)

But, there is still a work around for EL Captain and you can install Flavour 2. Have a look at this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/OSXElCapitan/comments/3mkh55/how_to_kinda_run_flavours_2_on_osx_el_capitan/).

Answer (score 1):

[NerdTool](http://mutablecode.com/apps/nerdtool.html) lets you put up .qtz as wallpaper!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions