# Change colour of browser address/search bar

Tags: macos, safari, xcode, google-chrome

In OSX would it be possible to change the background colour and/or text colour of the address/search bar input field of a browser (Chrome, Safari, etc)? Not just the highlight colour (System Prefs > General > Highlight color) but as a permanent colour change, independent of focused or highlight state.

Mock up attached.

I'm completely new to OSX/app development and have no idea if this style setting made in the operating system or in the browser app? (Or if it's even possible to change at all).

I'm currently interested in the possibilities of how to achieve this - with the ultimate end goal to be able to toggle the override on or off when necessary.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Search Bar highlight colour is controlled by a System Preference.

[image]

System Prefs > General > Highlight color

[image]

This works for Safari & Chrome - though it also changes your highlight system-wide.

Comment: That setting only affect the highlight / colour when focused. I'm after a way to change the colour when inactive or focused. Basically, for it to not be black text on a white background.

Comment: Unfocussed selected is grey, unfocussed unselected is white, presumably also system-wide, as it's part of the same structure. Would have saved me some time & effort if you'd mentioned that detail in your original question :/ Essentially, it can't be done as easily as before - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222785/osx-el-captain-customization-and-themeing

Comment: OK. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way to do it is on the website developer's end. It can be accomplished, at least on Chrome, by adding a META tag to the HEAD of the web page's source code.

The META tag should have the value of `theme-color` and a valid colour HEX code, RGB code or CSS color value.

There's further information available from the Chrome Platform Status web site at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5398016231997440.

Hope that helps to sum this up, even if it isn't the answer you were looking for.

Comment: This only appears to work for Chrome on Android. I'm after a way to do it on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox allows you to install a theme for your firefox browser. They off hundreds of themes which affect the colors oh the top part of browser window. Solid themes are included. Googe "Firefox themes" and it will take you to page to sample and install a theme. Installing is simple. After sampling one of their themes you'll get an option to install.

The Chrome browser also allows themes.